# OS X 10.10 Safari 8 jquery ui tabs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jquery-ui-tabs

I've OS X 10.10 with Safari 8 having an issue with jquery ui tabs. I've tested the webpage on microsoft edge, chrome and firefox and everything works fine. On safari all the divs are displayed as tabs are not there at all. I'm using these versions of jquery and jquery ui. I have other jquery code on the same page that works fine the only issue is with tabs.

jquery: 1.11.1 
jqueryui: 1.11.1 
css: jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css

The tabs div has the class "ui-tabs ....." and the ul has the class "ui-tabs-nav ....." and list items li has class "ui-state-default ....." but divs don't have any classes they have just the id.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    show: 'fade', hide: 'fade'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs were in Arabic characters after changing these names to English it worked fine so it's an encoding issue not jquery issue but still don't know why Safari has this encoding issue while edge, chrome and firefox don't.